# iOS suppressing system WiFi Selection Alert

Tags: ios, wifi, alerts

I've been reading about cbcentralmanager and how you can use it to suppress the bluetooth alerts.

I have a requirement for a project I'm working on to suppress the WiFi network selection alert that comes up with you are on a carrier data network.

I'm not finding any way to do it without using private methods.

Does anyone know a way to make the WiFi selection alert not come up when a user is in our app when they have an active data connection?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to not be possible due to restrictions in the OS>